# add method to angular FormControl class

Tags: typescript, prototype

I am taking the example of FormControl but it could be applied to any constructor method within a module.

Let's say I would like to add the method `myMethod(string): FormControl` to the existing FormControl class from ReactiveForm.

I thought I could do it this way:

```
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

declare module '@angular/forms' {
  interface FormControl {
    myMethod(value: string): FormControl;
  }
}

FormControl.prototype.myMethod = function(value) { /*TODO*/ };

const formControl = new FormControl('').myMethod('hello');
```

I would have worked with pure javacript,
but I have several warnings and errors during typescript compilation:

- ShadowedName: FormControl
- 'FormControl' only refers to a type but is used as a value here

Actualy, I think I understand both of the messages, but how can I do here?
I have read the official type script documentation on it (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) and cannot find a case that matchs mine...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FormControl` actually comes from another module within angular, that is the one you need to augment. I found that out by using go to definition command in Visual Studio Code. Also I took the liberty of adding a `this` parameter to your augmentation function:

```
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
declare module '@angular/forms/src/model' {
  interface FormControl {
    myMethod(value: string): FormControl;
  }
}
FormControl.prototype.myMethod = function(this: FormControl, value: string) { 
  return this;
};
const formControl = new FormControl('').myMethod('hello');
```

Comment: At first I wasn't really convinced, then I read somewhere that augmentation must be done on sources and not on already existing declarations. So this is definitely the right answer. Thanks

Comment: This works well - don't forget to  - import './my-extension'; - in your component file